# JavaScript closure within eventlistener

Tags: javascript, closures

```
<button>test</button>
<button>test</button>
<button>test</button>
<button>test</button>
<button>test</button>
<script>
var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
function clicked(i){
    console.log('pass');

    // Closure
    // return function(){
    //  console.log(i);
    // }

}
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
   nodes[i].addEventListener('click', clicked(i));
}
</script>
```

I am try to have a fully understanding on js closure, the above function add even listener to the buttons. it console log 'pass' 5 times and then does nothing when button clicked. but if i uncomment out the closure bit (return), console.log will echo out the i, but not log 'pass'. I did find relevant answer but i don't get why with closure onclick doesn't log the '**pass**' string when button clicked instead does log out the **i**.

[How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?page=1&tab=oldest#tab-top)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing here is directly calling the function `clicked` instead of setting it as an event handler.

> i don't get why with closure onclick doesn't log the 'pass' string when button clicked instead does log out the i.

well, your closure was

```
return function(){
  console.log(i);
}
```

Why would that log anything except `i` ?

The function that creates this closure should log "pass" five times during page initialization (as you call five times in the loop, each time it logs a line and returns the closure).

You could use `bind`.

```
nodes[i].addEventListener('click', clicked.bind(nodes[i], i));
```

This will give you `i` as a parameter to the function, so that you can do

```
console.log("pass", i);
```

Comment: This answer is awesome... You last edit make things even clearly. Big ty

Comment: actually this works as well
nodes[i].addEventListener('click', clicked.bind(nodes, i));

Comment: Yes. You can set that first parameter to whatever you want. It determines what `this` will be inside of your event handler (but you are not using that). You can test it with `console.info(this)`. Binding it to the element that was being clicked on (`nodes[i]`) could come in handy if you want to refer to that DOM node (reading attributes or something like that).

Comment: i c, that's right i am not using this. Thanks again

Comment: @RobG: Yes, that's why I proposed to bind to `nodes[i]`, which is the element on which the listener was placed.

Comment: @Thilo—doh, missed the `[i]` bit. :-o

Comment: But the OP is asking about and trying to understand closures... aren't you going off track a bit with bind?

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to answer the original question as asked...

> but i don't get why with closure onclick doesn't log the 'pass' string
>   when button clicked instead does log out the i

Go back to your code without the commented out section...

```
<button>test</button>
<button>test</button>
<button>test</button>
<button>test</button>
<button>test</button>
<script>
    var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
    function clicked(i) {
        console.log('pass');

         //Closure
         return function(){
          output(i);
         }

    }
    function output(i) {
        alert('The value of the closure i for this button is: '+i);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        nodes[i].addEventListener('click', clicked(i));
    }
</script>
<style>
    html {
        counter-reset: button-count -1;
    }

    button:after {
        content: ' ' counter(button-count);
        counter-increment: button-count;
    }
</style>
```

(I also added a little extra to help explain)

When you initialise the event listeners in the `for loop`, you are passing the *return value* of `clicked(i)` as the function pointer to be called when the click occurs on `node[i]`.
In your original code, the return value is a reference to an ***anonymous function*** defined as:

```
function(){
  console.log(i);
 }
```

So this is what is executed when you click button i - not `clicked`.
`clicked` is only executed during the `for loop`.  You will see pass one time for each button in the console due to the `for loop`.

The lexical scope for the ***anonymous function*** includes the scope of it's containing function `clicked` so the parameter `i` is *in scope* for the ***anonymous function***.  Each time `clicked` terminates, during the `for loop`, a separate ***closure*** is created on the parameter `i`, preserving it's value for that particular call.

In the code above, I created a function called output that receives a parameter i, so this

```
function(){
  output(i);
}
```

... is called when you click button i: also having a closure on `i`.

I also added some CSS styling to number the buttons.